# SQL Server - Null value in set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone explain why

```
 SELECT bl_id
  FROM bl
 WHERE bl_id NOT IN (SELECT bl_id FROM eq
                      WHERE bl_id IS NOT NULL)
```

returns 1,483 rows. 
But ,

```
 SELECT bl_id
  FROM bl
 WHERE bl_id NOT IN (SELECT bl_id FROM eq)
```

returns 0 rows?

I realize it has to do with the fact that "SELECT bl_id FROM eq" can return a bl_id that can be null.

But what I don't understand is f even one of the bl_id values is null the outer WHERE clause will never return true. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is how `NOT IN` works.  I *strongly* recommend that you learn to use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT bl_id
FROM bl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM eq
                  WHERE eq.bl_id = bl.bl_id
                 );
```

This has the semantics that you expect.

The reason is because `NULL` in SQL means "unknown".  It is *not* a specific value.  Hence, if you have these:

```
where 1 not in (1, 2, 3)
where 1 not in (2, 3)
```

Then SQL can evaluate the first to "false" and the second to "true".  However, if you have:

```
where 1 not in (1, 2, 3, NULL)
where 1 not in (2, 3, NULL)
```

Then the first is "false", because "1" is in the set.  The second is `NULL`, because we don't know what value `NULL` might be, and it could be `1`.  Hence, `NOT IN` with a `NULL` value in the subset always returns "false" or `NULL`, and neither of these possibilities is true.